# How to create 2D-Grid, raster or heatmap based on group values that include NAs?

Tags: r, heatmap, r-raster

Following data:

```
df <- data.frame(cbind("Group_ID" = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4), "WBHO" = runif(20, 1.0, 7.0), "SI" = runif(20, 1.0, 7.0), "OORT" = c(2.34, 4.64, NA, 5.32, 3.23, 6.01, 5.43, 4.78, 3.98, 3.80, 4.45, NA, NA, 3.18, 4.87, NA, NA, 5.73, 3.52, 4.89), "LMX" = runif(20, 1.0, 7.0),"RL" = runif(20, 1.0, 7.0),"AL" = c(1.54, NA, 1.08, 6.77, NA, NA, 4.56, NA, 5.34, 4.32, 2.45, 3.86, 6.21, 2.89, 7.32, 6.43, NA, 4.56, 3.89, 6.16),"SL" = runif(20, 1.0, 7.0),"RV" = runif(20, 1.0, 7.0),"PT" = runif(20, 1.0, 7.0),"SD" = runif(20, 1.0, 7.0), "HT" = runif(20, 1.0, 7.0), "RTL" = c(2.45, NA, 6.04, 2.88, 3.49, 2.30, NA, 5.32, 2.39, NA, 3.62, 3.22, 4.87, 2.91, 5.41, NA, NA, 4.78, 6.20, NA), "INB" = runif(20, 1.0, 7.0), "ETB" = runif(20, 1.0, 7.0)))
```

Now, I want to create a raster, 2D-Grid or Heatmap which gives a nice overview of all the variables for each group ("Group_ID") using the mean (the x-axis showing the groups and the y-axis all the variables), giving a particular field green colour for value 1 to 3, yellow for 3 to 5 and green for 5 to 7. I have the following Code to create a df that combines the variables in one column and has the values and Group-belonging in the other two:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
gather(key = "variable", value = "value", - Group_ID) -> df_new
```

This does not work, however, as there are NAs included. However, I want to keep those rows with NAs. Is there a way with which I can do this in the same step?

Then, I would like to create the raster concerning which I have been given the following code which I am not fully sure how to apply in this case:

```
library(raster)

r <- raster(ncol=nrow(df_new), nrow=15, xmn=0, xmx=4, ymn=0, ymx=15)
values(r) <- as.vector(as.matrix(df$WBHO, df$SI, df$OORT, df$LMX, df$RL, df$AL, df$SL, df$RV, df$PT, df$SD, df$HT, df$RTL,
                             df$INB, df$ETB)
plot(r, axes=F, box=F, asp=NA)
axis(1, at=seq(), 0:9)
axis(2, at=seq(), c("", colnames(df_new)), las=1)
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `dplyr` and `tidyr` to calculate the mean. After that, we can use the `cut` function to categorize the values. We can then use the `geom_tile` from the `ggplot2` to plot a heatmap. Specify `x` to be the `variable`, `y` is `Group_ID` (converted to be factor), and `fill` to be based on `value2`. No `raster` package is required.

It is not clear why do you want two groups (1-3, 5-7), both being green. My example assign red to the group 5-7, but you can make changes easily based on your needs.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_new <- df %>%
  gather(key = "variable", value = "value", - Group_ID) %>%
  group_by(Group_ID, variable) %>%
  summarise(value = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  mutate(value2 = cut(value, breaks = c(1, 3, 5, 7), labels = c("Low", "Medium", "High"))) %>%
  ungroup()

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df_new, aes(x = variable, y = factor(Group_ID), fill = value2)) +
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Low" = "Green", "Medium" = "Yellow", "High" = "Red")) + 
  labs(
    y = "Group_ID"
  )
```

[image]

Comment: OP mentions mean. I think something along the lines of `aggregate(value ~ key + Group_ID, data = df_new, FUN = mean)` should be added?

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Now I see that there are multiple values per group. I have updated my post to calculate the mean and categorize the value to different groups.

Comment: Thank you both :)